# How do I write a 3D histogram code without the Matlab built in functions?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I want to creat a histogram code, knowing that it'll be counting the number of occurence of 3 values of a pixel.
The idea is I have 3 matrices (L1im, L2im, L3im) representing information extracted from an image, size of each of them is 256*226, and I want to compute how many times a combination of let's say (52,6,40) occurs (each number correspends to a matrix/component but they're all of the same pixel).

I have tried this, but it doesn’t produce the right result:

```
for i = 1 : 256
    for j = 1 : 256
        for k = 1 : 256
            if  (L1im == i) &  (L2im == j) & (L3im == k)
                myhist(i,j,k)= myhist(i,j,k)+1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What are `L1im` and the other two values? What kind of “information extracted from an image” do they have? Also, there is lots of code out there for color histogram, did you search on Google to find those?

Comment: The L1im, L2im and L3im are 3 output matrices that i got from an lbp based method each of them is in size 256*256. i don't know if i explained well what i want from the histogram to do, but to simplify it, the histogram should be counting the occurrence of 3 values combined. And no, it's not from google, it's just me trying to find a way

Comment: “Just me trying to find a way” — do this through Google. You’ll find lots of existing implementations that you can learn from. For example I found this one just now: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43630-color-histogram-of-an-rgb-image — I’m sure you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Okey, i'll check it out and Thank you @Cris. although i have a general question (kinda confusion) about histogram of rgb images, when we use for example Matlab histogram function and it gives us a histogram with bars, what does each bin represent exactly ? knowing there are 3 channels and yet in the histogram it's seems like it's one representation presented as bars ?

Comment: `histogram` treats all values in the array equally, the output contains information about each individual value, not about triplets. Doesn’t matter if you interpret your 3D array as an RGB image or not, `histogram` never does.

Comment: okey, Thank you for the explanation and time, appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Colour Triplets Histogram

Keeping in mind doing an entire RGB triplet histogram is a large task since you can have 256 × 256 × 256 = 16,777,216 combinations of possible unique colours. A slightly more manageable task I believe is to compute the histogram for the unique RGB values in the image (since the rest will be zero anyways). This is still a fairly large task but might be reasonable if the image is fairly small. Below I believe a decent alternative to binning is to resize the image to a smaller number of pixels. This can be done by using the `imresize` function. I believe this will decrease fidelity of the image and almost act as a rounding function which can "kinda" simulate the behaviour of binning. In this example I convert the matrices string arrays an concatenate the channels, `L1im`, `L2im` and `L3im` of the image. Below is a demo where I use the image built into MATLAB named `saturn.png`. A `Resize_Factor`
of 1 will result in the highest amount of bins and the number of bins will decrease as the `Resize_Factor` increases. Keep in mind that the histogram might require scaling if the image is being resized with the `Resize_Factor`.

[image: RGB Triplet Histogram]

```
Resize_Factor = 200;
RGB_Image = imread("saturn.png");
[Image_Height,Image_Width,Number_Of_Colour_Channels] = size(RGB_Image);
Number_Of_Pixels = Image_Height*Image_Width;

RGB_Image = imresize(RGB_Image,[Image_Height/Resize_Factor Image_Width/Resize_Factor]);
L1im = RGB_Image(:,:,1);
L2im = RGB_Image(:,:,2);
L3im = RGB_Image(:,:,3);

L1im_String = string(L1im);
L2im_String = string(L2im);
L3im_String = string(L3im);

RGB_Triplets = L1im_String + "," + L2im_String + "," + L3im_String;
Unique_RGB_Triplets = unique(RGB_Triplets);

for Colour_Index = 1: length(Unique_RGB_Triplets)
    RGB_Colour = Unique_RGB_Triplets(Colour_Index);
    Unique_RGB_Triplets(Colour_Index,2) = nnz(RGB_Colour == RGB_Triplets); 
end

Counts = str2double(Unique_RGB_Triplets(:,2));
Scaling_Factor = Number_Of_Pixels/sum(Counts);
Counts = Counts.*Scaling_Factor;

if sum(Counts) == Number_Of_Pixels
    disp("Sum of histogram is equal to the number of pixels");
end

bar(Counts);
title("RGB Triplet Histogram");
xlabel("RGB Triplets"); ylabel("Counts");

Current_Axis = gca;
Scale = (1:length(Unique_RGB_Triplets));
set(Current_Axis,'xtick',Scale,'xticklabel',Unique_RGB_Triplets);
Angle = 90;
xtickangle(Current_Axis,Angle);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelTr7 for your help, that's exactly what i want. i have one question, the unique fonction returns the unique elements in the array without repetition, wouldn't that influence the count of occurrences of the triplets, hence the histogram ?

Comment: The `unique()` function in this case is used to only build a dictionary of colour/triplets values present in the image. After getting this triplet dictionary we count the occurrences using the `RGB_Triplets` variable which stores all the triplets in the image.

Comment: Keep in mind that the histogram might require scaling (multiplied by a calculated number) if the image is being resized with the `Resize_Factor`.

Comment: Okey well understood for the unique() function. can you please elaborate abt the scaling ..i mean why would we need it ? and normalization is a kind of scaling, would it be good ?

Comment: I updated the script in my answer to include scaling. The scaling is used to combat the resizing done to simulate binning. By resizing the image we now have far fewer pixels representing the image. Essentially the colour pixels that are similar to each other get binned to one value. For example 1 pixel in the resized (smaller) image may actually represent 4 pixels in the original image if the resize factor is 2.

Comment: Got it. i can't thank you enough for your help and time you put into it, i appreciate it so much.